# Footer menu goes top of main container

Tags: css, css-float, overflow, footer

I have three main divs , they are `header`,`main-container` and `footer`. CSS for the divs are

```
#main_container
{
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
#header
{
    background:#f4f8f9;
}
#footer
{
    clear:both;
    background:#355e95;
    height:40px;
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Franklin Gothic", "ITC Franklin Gothic", Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Now, in the index page, there were no left -right floating so the footer is in bottom. But in the subsequent pages, there are lots of floating, now the footer goes above `main-container` ! Why this happens? I have cleared `floating` before `footer` div

```
<div class="clr"></div> 
    <div id="footer">
         &copy;2010 Sri Sai Group
         <div class="fbtm">
            Powered,Maintained and Designed By <a href="http://7sisters.in" target="_blank">7sisters.in</a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

NB when I add `overflow:auto;` page is coming like this !
[image: edited css page]

FULL HTML FOR ONE OF MY PAGE:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="htop">
            <div class="phn">Ph +0361-26699811</div>

            <div class="email">Email support@7sisters.in</div>

        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="menu_wrapper">
            <div class="menu_outer">

                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="css/images/logo.png" alt="Sri sai" />
                </div>

                <div class="menu">
                    <div id="site_title">
                        <h1>SRI SAI GROUP</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id='cssmenu'>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
                              <ul>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Overview</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Board Members</span></a>

                                 </li>

                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Our Family</span></a>

                                 </li>

                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Gratitude</span></a>

                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Business</span></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Food and Beverages</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Media and Entertaintment</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Information Technology</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Consumer Servies</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 </ul>   
                           </li>
                           <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
              </div>   
         </div>

         <div id="web-design">
      <img src="css/images/banner_ssg.png" />
    Our Website Development team builds websites using latest technologies; the sites we build are robust, secure and reliable. Our process guarantees fast capturing of your idea and quick Website Development at minimum possible cost.

During the Website Development process we keep provisions for future growth of your business. The sites we build are SEO compatible. You will get professional developers that are personally dedicated to you and ready to meet your business objectives.

All our projects come with the needed documentation and support.
    </div>
        <div id="contact_form">

        <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
                <span id="nameInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
                <span id="phoneInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="message">Address&nbsp;</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
                <span id="emailInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass2">Website&nbsp;</label>
                <select>
                    <option>Static</option>
                    <option>Dynamic</option>
                </select>    
                <span id="pass2Info"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>


    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>    


    </div>



    <div class="clr"></div> 
    <div id="footer">
         &copy;2010 Sri Sai Group
         <div class="fbtm">
            Powered,Maintained and Designed By <a href="http://7sisters.in" target="_blank">7sisters.in</a>
         </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Please post the full html for one of the pages which is causing a problem. Is it floating elements within #main_container ? If so you may want ti try adding "overflow: hidden" to #main_container and see if that sorts it out for you.

Comment: If I add overflow:hidden; the contents within `main-container` disappears !

Comment: It looks like it's not the #main_container witch presents a problem, it's what is inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you need to do is close your maincontent div before the footer, it is missing one there to do so (if you believe you already have it isn't).

```
            <div>
            <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div></div>



<div class="clr"></div> 
<div id="footer">
     &copy;2010 Sri Sai Group
     <div class="fbtm">
        Powered,Maintained and Designed By <a href="http://7sisters.in"
   target="_blank">7sisters.in</a>
     </div>
```

Also, maybe look at making maincontent width a % to stop it from extending too far on some browsers.

```
#main_container
{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `overflow:auto` to your `#main_container` css so it grows in height according to the size of its child elements. Then the `#footer` will be directly after `#main_container` which means after all content.

```
#main_container
{
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: auto; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Just read your updated answer. You probably have to add more of your HTML to your OP in order for this problem to be tackled. Most likely there are more containers that need `overflow:auto` because they aren't growing according to their content.

Answer (score 0):

put this structure.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="htop">
            <div class="phn">Ph +0361-26699811</div>

            <div class="email">Email support@7sisters.in</div>

        </div>


    </div>

    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="menu_wrapper">
            <div class="menu_outer">

                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="css/images/logo.png" alt="Sri sai" />
                </div>

                <div class="menu">
                    <div id="site_title">
                        <h1>SRI SAI GROUP</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id='cssmenu'>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
                              <ul>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Overview</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Board Members</span></a>

                                 </li>

                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Our Family</span></a>

                                 </li>

                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Gratitude</span></a>

                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Business</span></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Food and Beverages</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Media and Entertaintment</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Information Technology</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Consumer Servies</span></a>

                                 </li>
                                 </ul>   
                           </li>
                           <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
              </div>   
         </div>

         <div id="web-design">
      <img src="css/images/banner_ssg.png" />
    Our Website Development team builds websites using latest technologies; the sites we build are robust, secure and reliable. Our process guarantees fast capturing of your idea and quick Website Development at minimum possible cost.

During the Website Development process we keep provisions for future growth of your business. The sites we build are SEO compatible. You will get professional developers that are personally dedicated to you and ready to meet your business objectives.

All our projects come with the needed documentation and support.
    </div>
        <div id="contact_form">

        <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
                <span id="nameInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
                <span id="phoneInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="message">Address&nbsp;</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
                <span id="emailInfo"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass2">Website&nbsp;</label>
                <select>
                    <option>Static</option>
                    <option>Dynamic</option>
                </select>    
                <span id="pass2Info"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>


    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>    

    <div class="clr"></div> 
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
         &copy;2010 Sri Sai Group
         <div class="fbtm">
            Powered,Maintained and Designed By <a href="http://7sisters.in" target="_blank">7sisters.in</a>
         </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```